# Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' Object required: 'objIE.document.getElementById(..)

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to automate a webpage.

I was able to do login and click on the page.
After i click in the new page i need to enter "Name" into it, but its not working getting : Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' Object required: 'objIE.document.getElementById(..)

below is the code i am using

```
struser = "user"
strPass = "pswd"
 Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 objIE.Visible = True
objIE.Navigate "http://myurl"
While objIE.Busy = True
WScript.Sleep 100
Wend
While objIE.ReadyState <> 4
WScript.Sleep 100
Wend
objIE.Document.all.User.value = struser
objIE.Document.all.Password.value = strPass
objIE.Document.Forms(0).Submit()
While objIE.Busy = True
WScript.Sleep 100
Wend
While objIE.ReadyState <> 4
WScript.Sleep 100
Wend
objIE.Document.all.drop_mainmenu.click()
objIE.Document.all.BOX.value = "12"
objIE.Document.all.Button.Click()
While objIE.Busy = True
WScript.Sleep 100
Wend
While objIE.ReadyState <> 4
WScript.Sleep 100
Wend
'dim srch
'objIE.Document.getElementsByName("0_58").value = "Long"
'srch.value = "Long"
 set el = objIE.document.getElementById("C0_58") 
'If el.value is nothing Then
 set el.value = "Long"
'End If
 Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 WshShell.SendKeys "^%L"

below is the snippet of source code for that field.

enter code here<input name="0_58" tabindex="6" title="Alpha Name" class="textfield" id="C0_58" style="width: 218px; 
vertical-align: top; cursor: auto;" onmouseover="updateHelpCursor('',this)" onhelp="hp('0_58')" 
onfocus="FCHandler.onFocus(this,'',false)" onblur="FCHandler.onExit(this,false,'',false)" 
type="text" maxlength="40" value=" " htmlpostflag="false">

enter code here
```

Comment: Does this work ??

set el = objIE.document.getElementById("C0_58")..... Enclose the ID in Double Quotes

Comment: same error with set el = objIE.document.getElementById("C0_58")

Comment: forgot to update, this field is inside an iframe which got multiple tables  and spans  inside it.

Comment: Then there might be a problem with the objIE object. 

Do you get an error with 'objIE .Visible = True' statement. Try putting it before set el = objIE.document.getElementById(C0_58)... If this also throws error, your IE object is not set correctly or not passed to this object correctly. Can you please post the code from where this objIE coming.

Comment: struser = "user"
    strPass = "pswd"
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.Navigate "http://myurl"
    While objIE.Busy = True
 WScript.Sleep 100
    Wend
    While objIE.ReadyState <> 4
 WScript.Sleep 100
    Wend

Comment: objIE.Document.all.User.value = struser
    objIE.Document.all.Password.value = strPass
    objIE.Document.Forms(0).Submit()
    While objIE.Busy = True
 WScript.Sleep 100
    Wend

Comment: While objIE.ReadyState <> 4
 WScript.Sleep 100
    Wend
    objIE.Document.all.drop_mainmenu.click()
    objIE.Document.all.BOX.value = "12"
    objIE.Document.all.Button.Click()
    While objIE.Busy = True
 WScript.Sleep 100
    Wend
    While objIE.ReadyState <> 4
 WScript.Sleep 100
    Wend
        set el = objIE.document.getElementById("C0_58") 
     'If el.value is nothing Then
     set el.value = "Long"
     'End If
     Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
     WshShell.SendKeys "^%L"

Comment: Very hard to read. Instead, update your original post to reflect this code. Would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Surprising, I have tried the below code and it works perfectly when saved and executed from a vbs file.

```
 Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
 objIE.Visible = True
 objIE.Navigate "https://www.google.co.in/"
 Wscript.Sleep(5000)

 Set objEL = objIE.Document.GetElementById("lst-ib")
 objEL.Value = "Mithilesh"
 MsgBox objEL.Value 'Displays Mithilesh
```

Also, the below might not be useful in resolving the error you are getting but look at the way I am setting the value in the field. You should not use

```
set el.value = "Long"
```

Instead use

```
el.value = "Long"
```

Try this

```
ObjIE.Document.Frames("Iframe").contentwindow.document.getElementsById("C0_58")
```

Or:

```
For Each frame In iframes
    Set inputs = frame.contentwindow.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each obj In inputs
        If obj.className = "C0_58" Then
            'MsgBox "found "C0_58" in frame:" & i
        End If
    Next
i = i + 1
Next
```

The best I could suggest is to play around the frames and their child elements. If possible, you could post your HTML, we could have a look at that

Comment: I tired the same el.value = "Long" but still same issue.

Comment: Is it because the field is inside an Iframe foillowed by few tables, followed by span and divs ?
Is there any relation how the fileds were inside the HTML source.

Comment: I tried it with the below:
ObjIE.Document.Frames("Iframe").Document.All("C0_58").Value = "Long"

this time i did not get any error but the filed is not getting populated with the value.

Comment: Searching on google, I could make out this.



The best you can do is, loop through the frame's childelements and see if one of the names matches your inputbox 

I am updating my previous answer for indentation purpose.

Comment: Tried with 
set ifr = ObjIE.Document.Frames("Iframe").contentwindow.document.getElementsById("C0_58")
ifr.value = "Long"

But same, no error popped UP

Comment: For Each frame In Iframe
    Set inputs = frame.contentwindow.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each obj In inputs
        If obj.className = "C0_58" Then
            Wscript.echo "found " & i
        End If
    Next
i = i + 1
Next

Tried this, but getting erro "Objectt not a collection" Code : 800A01C3